# Alert before deleting data from Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want an alert to display to make sure the user will double confirm if they want to delete the data.

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="del.php?masId=<?php echo $row['masId'] ?>" >delete</a>
```

My php code:

```
$masId = $_GET['masId'];

$res=$MySQLiconn->query("Delete FROM masinflation WHERE masId=".$masId);
```

However, the data still will be removed even I click cancel.

Comment: onclick="javascript:alert...."

Comment: Side Note: What you're attempting to do will only confirm that the user *clicked the link*.  Should any user visit that destination URL manually or by any other means, there would be no confirmation.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: take a button and on click of button use var confirmation = confirm('are your sure you want to delete.'); if(confirmation) { Ajax request to delete or get the data-id by putting as data-attribute for button}

Comment: A better method would be an ajax method that gets fired through jquery on clicking a button or link, with confirm, if confirm == true, then fire the ajax method that runs a separate php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code which will prevent default behavior of anchor tag if you click on cancel button.

```
<a class="confirmation" href="del.php?masId=<?php echo $row['masId'] ?>" >delete</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
    var confirmIt = function (e) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
    };
    for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="return checkDelete()" href="del.php?masId=<?php echo $row['masId'] ?>" >delete</a>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkDelete(){
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This code is working as when I use javascript, other than just using 'return confirm' in the button

Comment: It's the same thing. Everything inside the `onclick=""` is evaluated and run as javascript. `confirm()` is just a function as well.